# Setup script before docker compose in Visual Studio Code

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am using Visual Studio Code with Docker on the project I am working on. I connect to the machine via SSH. I am having issues with properly setting up the environment when trying to run Compose Up. The docker-compose.yaml uses some environment variables that are set by a shell script, so I need to execute it before Compose Up. What would be the best way to do it?

Currently I have overriden the "docker.commands.composeUp: command like this:

```
"docker.commands.composeUp": [
    
    {
        "label": "Compose Up",
        "template": "source env_setup.sh && ${composeCommand} ${configurationFile} up ${detached} ${build}"
    }
]
```

but I think it is not the best solution. Because then I need to also override "docker.commands.composeUpSubset". I also tried writing task, but "docker-compose" type of task does not have ability to add any command or script before execution to setup environment.